# Include only tracked files with npm publish

Tags: git, npm

By default all files are published from package directory with

```
npm publish .
```

even if they are not tracked by Git. Untracked files can be random temporary files that aren't covered by .gitignore or .npmignore and may include sensitive data.

Is there a way to avoid untracked files from being accidentally published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to try [publish-please](https://github.com/inikulin/publish-please) as replacement:

As it claimed, it will do a lot of validations before publishing to the registry.

> Check that there are no untracked files in the working tree.

Answer (score 1):

Do not publish from your working repository. Clone a clean repo and publish from it. When you have new development just update the clean repo with `git pull` and publish again. The clean repo could be a repo at Continuous Integration server so if all tests passed CI server publishes automatically.